# XML and HTML = need help using HTML code

Tags: php, xml

I'm converting my static HTML site to a dynamic PHP/XML-driven one.
This is my current code:

```
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="main" style="width: 552px;">
   <div class="time">00:00</div>
   <div class="show"><h3><b>Radio Show</b></h3>
    <p>Description</p></div>
   <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
```

and my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<show>
 <showdesc>
 <divider1></divider1>
 <divmain></divmain>
 <airtime></airtime>
 <presenter></presenter>
    <showinfo></showinfo>
    <divfooter></divfooter>
    </showdesc>
```

which is the above HTML, that I'm trying to get into the XML file.
I don't know how to get it to get the info in, I can display a simple XML page, as suggested here: http://www.kirupa.com/web/xml_php_parse_intermediate.htm
but I am trying to in PHP get this to display what's in the XML pages or display this output:
"Sorry. No schedule page is available" if the XML is blank, as above.

Anyone able to help me fix this? I've tried and tried but it's baffling me...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all the formatting stuff in your xml document. There are only three pieces of "real" information in the html snippet you've posted: `title`, `time` and `description` which you could format as

```
<show>
  <title>Radio Show</title>
  <time>00:00:00</time>
  <description>...</description>
</show>
```

In the example xml snippet there's also an element `presenter`. Where would that info be in the (existing) html data?